# Reality check – Has ES file explorer abandoned its pro version?

Tags: applications, google-drive, es-file-explorer

Has anybody else wondered if ES Global decided to make money with their Explorer app by abandoning the pro version altogether and milking the free version?

I have used ES file explorer for a long time. I've been having more and more problems with the pro version with regards to cloud networking, which is one of the features that I use most. Sometimes it grants me access to all Google Drives, other times not at all, and most frequently only to some drives.

I decided this morning to try their free version. Their free version  not only worked extremely well with Google Drive, the connection is much faster than the pro version. In contrast, they have apparently spent a lot of effort updating the crapware. Today it felt like trapware. I was asked to install other apps in order to access features. So I did, to test this, and immediately uninstalled them. I still had access to the features but I feel like I need to take a long hot shower.

Have other people seen this? Is this a new moneymaking  twist – offering a pro version without ads and updates while milking the free version? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried ES explorer for a short while. IMO any app that pushes crapware like that one is considered malware, add to the fact that I analysed the network traffic and it seems like they are routing all traffic through an unknown VPN. Totally not my cup of tea. Not going to suggest anything, but FX explorer fits all my needs now. I even paid for their pro version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment user218076. Absolutely no argument about the ES crapware. That's why I bought their pro version, which resolved that. Have you run into any apps that abandoned their pro version? FX may be a good app, but what if they abandon their pro version?  More importantly, how did you figure out they run things through a VPN? Thanks.

Comment: ES Explorer used to be the de facto standard file explorer, then it caved to crapware money and lost 80% of it's users... It realized it's mistake but it was too late. Today, and for probably 2 years, it's just been a shell living on it's old reputation and now it's just dying. I will also be flagging this as off-topic as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Yes I do have opinions about this. But if what I wanted to do is trash the software developer I be asking the question somewhere else. Is what I see correct -- they're ditching the pro version that I paid for? I've never heard of that kind of behavior before and  I'd like to verify that or explain it before I start posting negative reviews. And if they are sending my data out through a VPN I would like to know how to verify that, not  just accept it because someone here said it.

Comment: @IndirectPointer I haven't noticed yet another app that does this. FX Pro is not to remove ads it is to add some features. The free version has no ads whats so ever. I had a host blocker to block some sites, and ES's built in browser was still able to access them. Seems to be they are routing through proxy or vpn. Just checked with a Network Firewall app (AFWall+) with a log. Within a few minutes, the log list 100's of attempts to connect to a couple of different IP addresses. Also in settings, it by default opted me in to a "Customer Improvement Program"

Comment: I can't verify what user218076 said about ES file explorer mischief. I would not be surprised if that is true. In case someone else is unhappy with ES and is looking for a reputable alternative, similar in feel and scope. I am moving to the XDA OSS file Explorer, MiXplorer.  https://labs.xda-developers.com/store/app/com.mixplorer. So far so good. P.S. I found the facilitator of this group to be high-handed, and hypocritical in calling the dialogue only opinion when his comment was merely that.